# How to get a return value from a Task?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I have a task that needs to return a value, which is to be passed to the `ContinueWith`.
However, I have no idea what the `Task<<PlaceHolder>TResult>` / `Func<<PlaceHolder>TResult>` syntax is:

This is my current code:

```
var task = new Task(CreateAction(token), token, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
task.ContinueWith(_ => {/*...*/});
//...

Action CreateAction(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return async () => 
    {
       //... 
       // Need to modify this method to return a bool value
    }
}
```

I've tried this but it doesn't compile:

```
var task = new Task<bool>(CreateAction(token), token, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
task.ContinueWith((theReturnValue) => {/*...*/});
//...

Func<bool> CreateAction(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return async () => 
    {
       //... 
       return true; // hardcoded for example sake
    }
}
```

Comment: `return async () => true;` returns a `Func<Task<bool>>`, not a `Func<bool>`. `return () => true;` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *direct* answer is:

```cs
task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var foo = t.Result;
    // etc
});
```

however, `ContinueWith` probably isn't necessary here; this sounds like `await`:

```cs
var foo = await task;
```

Note also that `new Task(...)` is unusual (see "Remarks" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0)); I would expect more of `Task.Run` here.

Comment: Congratulations on your megarep!

Comment: @MatthewWatson finally a millionaire